# Getdate() sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to show some messages, so that i am doing a date comparison in sq l server,
my problem is that the message should show until the end date
for example ; end date is "2014-01-24" and i need to show that message until 25th begins
but my select statement wont allow me to show
my where condition is `GET DATE() BETWEEN Start Date AND End Date`
i saw that get date function  gets the value "2014-01-24 15:06:19.270" that's why the message didn't get.

Is there anyway to check "2014-01-24" instead of full "2014-01-24 15:06:19.270"..
please suggest

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) >= '20140124' 
                 AND CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= '20140125'
                  THEN 'Show Message' END
```

Comment: yes i used CAST(GET DATE() AS DATE) instead of just get date func and its working